# setq versus setq-local for tab-always-indent

Tags: buffer-local

Have found the `tab-always-indent` setting and wonder the appropriateness of

```
(setq tab-always-indent 'complete)
```

versus

```
(setq-local tab-always-indent 'complete)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setq-local` sets the value buffer-locally (i.e. for the buffer which is current when that code is evaluated).

`tab-always-indent` is not automatically buffer-local, so which one you use *will* make a difference, but I can't tell from your question what effect you're actually wanting.

If you don't want a buffer-local value, though, don't use `setq-local`.

Comment: Thank you.  I understand the meaning of buffer local variables.  What would be some real  work scenarios on `tab-always-indent` settings where you would want buffer-local.  Looks like a global setting is appropriate for most tasks considering it is not automatically buffer-local,

Comment: I can't think of a likely scenario.  What did you have in mind when you asked the question?

Comment: Have been working on files that use actual tabs for indentation, but they were introduced by the developer which commonly conflict with emacs automatic re-indentation.  `(setq tab-always-indent nil)` allows insertion of tab after indent.  Whereas `(setq tab-always-indent 'complete)` does completion.  Do you think that completion with tab a popular choice?

Comment: Does `tab-always-indent` always require `electric-indent-mode`?

Comment: I've no idea what's popular, and as far as I know electric-indent-mode doesn't care at all about tab-always-indent -- that mode is about indenting *without* typing the tab key.